# How to prevent substitution?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have a function:

$\bar{u}:=u[t,x,y,z]$   (1)

How do I prevent it from expanding and substituting in instructions like those following:

$\partial _t {\bar u}$   (2)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Mathematica expressions as asked:

```
OverBar[u]:=u[t,x,y,z]

D[ OverBar[u] , t]
```

Comment: Please include _Mathematica_ code, not latex expressions. Have you looked at `Hold`, `HoldForm` and related functions or `Defer`?

Comment: I think this question needs more context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like to display the expression without evaluation use `HoldForm`

```
HoldForm@D[OverBar[u], t]
```